# How to automatically call a JavaScript that modify a value before show this value?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am very new in JavaScript and I have the following problem to solve.

I have a table that contains this td cell:

```
<td class= "dateToConvert" width = "8.33%">
    <%=salDettaglio.getDataCreazione() != null ? salDettaglio.getDataCreazione() : "" %>
</td>
```

This retrieve a String from an object and show it into the cell

The problem is the retrieved string represent a **date** having the following horrible form: **20131204** and I have to convert it into the following form: **2013-12-04**.

So I am thinking to create a JavaScript that do this work when the value is retrieved.

My problem is: how can I do to automatically call the JavaScript before to show the value into the td cell? (So I show the modified output in the desired form)

**EDIT 1**:

So I have create this JavaScript function into my page:

```
function convertData() {
    var tds = document.querySelectorAll('.dateToConvert');
    [].slice.call(tds).forEach(function(td) {
        td.innerText = td.innerText.replace(/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/, '$1-$2-$3');
    });
 }
```

But it don't work because it never enter in this function (I see it using FireBug JavaScript debugger). Why? What am I missing? Maybe have I to call it explicitly in some way in my td cell?

Comment: Can you better fix `salDettaglio.getDataCreazione()`?

Comment: @dfsq No I can't. It is an object retrieved from a WebServices and I have not the code

Comment: I mean you should fix it on backend. Or ask bakend developer to do it for you. But of course you can run some javascript to convert it.

Comment: I can't ask it (it would result in a long series of changes elsewhere). How can run a JavaScript to do it?

Comment: you could do a custom function which would itself call this remote ressource and process the data before returning it. YOu would then call this custom function instead of the resource directly.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is better to fix backend method to make it return proper format. But since you have no control over it try to use something like this:

```
var tds = document.querySelectorAll('.dateToConvert');
[].slice.call(tds).forEach(function(td) {
    td.textContent = td.textContent.replace(/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/, '$1-$2-$3');
});
```

Check the demo below.

```js
var tds = document.querySelectorAll('.dateToConvert');
[].slice.call(tds).forEach(function(td) {
    td.textContent = td.textContent.replace(/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/, '$1-$2-$3');
});
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class= "dateToConvert" width = "8.33%">
            20131204 
        </td>
        <td class= "dateToConvert" width = "8.33%">
            20140408 
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I try to create a JavaScript function in my page using your code but I never enter in this function so this code is never performed. I edited my original post

Comment: Do you call this function `convertData()`?

Comment: You can add this line `window.onload = convertData`.